# NuGet restore on a TFS2013 from a VS2017 solutioin not working

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget-package-restore

I have run into the problem that if I have a VS2017 solution and try to build it on our TFS2013 build server it fails by not restoring the nuget-packages. If I convert this 2017 solution to VS2015 and check it in, and build it, the nuget-packages get restored.

I have tried with packages from both nuget.org and from internal nuget packages sources. So there is something that has changed between VS2017 and VS2015 regarding the automatic restore of nuget-packages. But I can't find the solution for it. Anybody else that has run into this problem...

Comment: What's the result if you build the solution and enable Nuget package restore in Visual Studio 2017 locally? This will narrow down if the issue related to TFS server/ build definition or not.  And what's detail error you got when TFS build failed? Could you update the related info in your question.

Comment: What kind of project you created in VS2017? If you're building a .net core project in TFS, it do have difference between VS 2015 and VS 2017. Install nuget packages in the .net core project in VS2015, it uses packages.config file. But in VS 2017, it uses [project.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/project-json) file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a .net core project, it do have difference between VS 2015 and VS 2017. Install nuget packages in the .net core project in VS 2015, it uses packages.config file. But in VS 2017, it does not using packages.config file any more.

1. You need to create a batch file, to run a dotnet restore command to restore nuget packages for your solution.

code:

```
 dotnet restore %TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY%\...\WebApplication1Core
```

2. You'd better using VS 2017 on your build agent to build your solution. You could refer to the last reply in this thread about using VS 2017 in XAML build: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f3c4fc0b-d9ee-474a-9d91-9c5810b074a2/how-to-get-vs-2017-working-with-tfs-2017-xaml-builds?forum=tfsbuild

In the end, I do suggest that you could upgrade your TFS to 2017 and using Vnext build to build your project created in VS 2017.